# How to write makefile for Python?

Tags: python, makefile

I have a set of python class files. I run the MainProgram.py on the Linux as `python MainProgram.py` which uses the rest of the class files.It reads from an input file and write an output file.

Until now I have hard-coded the input path and output path in the program. But now I am supposed to use makefile mechanism to get a list of input paths and list of output paths.

How to write this makefile? How can I invoke this makefile? What corresponding changes has to be made in my Python program to let it know that makefile is being used? After makefile is used how can I run my Python program now?

Comment: You don't need a ``Makefile``; what you need to do is write command line argument parsing code so your program accepts command line arguments. Have a read of or search for argparse

Comment: There are main paths from which I need to read the input file and my python program has to run using that input file.sometimes new input files will be added under any of these paths.